# Conditional probability

Tags: probability

"An independent auto repair garage has five brake overhauls scheduled today. Four out of ten overhauls require replacement of a particular part, of which the garage has three in stock. Thus if more than three of the jobs require the part there will be delays until it can be obtained. What is the probability of this happening?"

So, I understand that the probability of the part being needed is 2/5, and that the probability of a delay occurring is conditional on more than 3 customers needing the part. I don't understand how to calculate the probability of the delay.

Answer (score 2):

Probability of part being needed is $p = \frac{2}{5}$.

Let $X$ be the number of overhauls that require replacement, then $X \stackrel{d}{=} B(5,p)$.

Meaning for $\displaystyle P(X=k) = \binom{5}{k}p^k(1-p)^{5-k}$

You are interested in $P(X>3) = P(X=4)+P(X=5)$

$$P(X=4)+P(X=5) = \binom{5}{4}p^4(1-p)^{1}+p^5 = 8.7\%$$

Answer (score 0):

It will be the sum of the probability that 4 overhauls will need the part and the probability that all 5 will need that part.

The probability that 4 will need the part is

$P(\text{Overhaul needs part})^4\times P(\text{Overhaul doesn't need part})^1\times \text{(Number of ways to arrange 4 needs and 1 not need)}$

Probability that all 5 will need the overhaul is similar.